# MapReduce intermediate data output location

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

You have just executed a MapReduce job. Where is intermediate data written to after being emitted from the Mapper’s map method?

- **A.** Intermediate data in streamed across the network from Mapper to the Reduce and is never written to disk.
- **B.** Into in-memory buffers on the TaskTracker node running the Mapper that spill over and are written into HDFS.
- **C.** Into in-memory buffers that spill over to the local file system of the TaskTracker node running the Mapper.
- **D.** Into in-memory buffers that spill over to the local file system (outside HDFS) of the TaskTracker node running the Reducer
- **E.** Into in-memory buffers on the TaskTracker node running the Reducer that spill over and are written into HDFS.

Comment: Today I comment [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564358/how-mapper-or-reducer-writes-data-to-hdfs?noredirect=1#comment45514933_28564358) with you doubt. Short answer: The data is written in the Hard disk of the Node when Map task is executed. Not in memory, not in HDFS.

Answer (score 3):

TaskTracker is a demon responsible for spawning map and reduce workers and it usually resides on a datanode. Map and reduce jobs run in a buffer until a certain threshold is reached; at that point records are written to disk in the background (see [Memory Management](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Memory_Management) in Hadoop's MapReduce tutorial). The process of writing to disk after the threshold capacity is reached is also called *spill to disk*. Thresholds values are given by parameters (e.g. `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb`, `mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent`, for Map, that can be configured).

Answer A is off because intermediate data may be written to disk.

Answers B and E can be excluded because spilled intermediate data isn't written to HDFS but to the local filesystem.

Finally, D is wrong because the question is asking for intermediate data *of the Mapper’s map method*. Also, it's not necessary to specify "outside HDFS" because in Hadoop context *local filesystem* is always understood as non-HDFS.

So, the correct answer is C.

Answer (score 1):

The mapper output (intermediate data) is stored on the Local file system (NOT HDFS) of each individual mapper nodes. This is typically a temporary directory location which can be setup in config by the hadoop administrator. The intermediate data is cleaned up after the Hadoop Job complete

i think this is the parameter that has to be modified to change the intermediate data location

mapreduce.cluster.local.dir

Answer (score 1):

The mapper output is stored on a local filesystem (Not HDFS) of the tasktracker node. So your answer is option "C"